# Routing and URL(Controller/Function) not working in codeigniter running on docker

Tags: php, docker, codeigniter

I am trying to set the url localhost:8080/main/testfunction but it says that `The requested URL was not found on this server.`

localhost:8080 is working and it redirects to main/index

my .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /booking/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

fixed this by adding this in Dockerfile

```
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```